# Error with print dialog in wxpython

Tags: wxpython

Here is my code:

```
def Print(self, e):
        data = wx.PrintDialogData()
        data.EnableSelection(True)
        data.EnablePrintToFile(True)
        data.EnablePageNumbers(True)
        data.SetMinPage(1)
        data.SetMaxPage(5)
        data.SetAllPages(True)
        dlg = wx.PrintDialog(self, data)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            data = dlg.GetPrintDialogData()
            self.log.write('GetAllPages: %d\n' % data.GetAllPages())
        dlg.Destroy()
```

When I try to open the Print menu option I get this error:

```
data.SetAllPages(True)
AttributeError: 'PrintDialogData' object has no attribute 'SetAllPages'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `PrintDialogData` does not have a `SetAllPages` attribute.
I suspect you have misinterpreted the use of the `data.GetAllPages()` function,
which Returns True if the user requested that all pages be printed, **after** calling the dialog.
i.e. It is set to True within the `PrintDialog` function if the user selects the "All pages" option, False otherwise.

```
def Print(self, e):
        data = wx.PrintDialogData()
        data.EnableSelection(True)
        data.EnablePrintToFile(True)
        data.EnablePageNumbers(True)
        data.SetMinPage(1)
        data.SetMaxPage(5)
        dlg = wx.PrintDialog(self,data)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            data = dlg.GetPrintDialogData()
            print (data.GetAllPages())
        dlg.Destroy()
```

Note that you should `Get` all the return values from the dialog that you require, before the `dlg.Destroy()`

Comment: Thank you but is this Print dialog functional(can it actually print)?

Comment: @blinkdocs I have to admit, I've never used it, as it seems too complicated for my requirements. For further info see: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/printing_framework_overview.html or https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/453413/printing-in-wxpython